# Java two equal signs in one statement?

Tags: java, linked-list

Can someone help me understand what the following code does and what the line with two equal sign does? How does something equal to something equal to something work in this constructor?

```
public More ...LinkedList() {
      header.next = header.previous = header;
 }
```

Here is the link to the website where I saw this and I'm trying to figure it out:
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/LinkedList.java#LinkedList.0header

Comment: It is not equality (==), but assignment (=).

Answer (score 12):

Read assignment statement from right to left:

1. assign `header` to `header.pevious`
2. assign `header.previous` to `header.next`

The bottom line: after this line both `header.previous` `header.next` will refer to `header`.

Comment: Must be nice to get four upvotes for the same answer when everyone else gets zero. Any tips on how to pull that off?

Comment: @jeremyjjbrown, I did my best... But I have one voice only...

Comment: how about concurrent scenerios?

Answer (score 5):

A single = is the assignment operator. This is a way to do multiple assignment in one line of code. It is setting header.next and header.previous to the value of header.

1. header.next = header.previous = header;

Is the same as...

1. header.next = header;
2. header.previous = header;

Answer (score 5):

`header.next` and `header.previous` have same value of `header`.

Example:

```
int val1 = 10;
int val2 = 11;
int val3 = val2 = val1;
```

Here  At last `val1`,`val2` & `val3` has the same value as `10`

Answer (score 3):

This means both `header.next` and `header.previous` will be set to `header`.

Answer (score 3):

Its as simple and as similar as a = b = 10 were value 10 is assign to variable b (b=10) and then value of variable b is assign to variable 10 (therefore a = 10). Please see [here](http://www.freejavaguide.com/assignment_operators.htm) for more details.